# Calculating the resistance of curved resistive paste deposits

Tags: resistance, coil, resistivity

I want to make a pcb heater element using a graphite paste deposited by stencil onto a substrate. I want to insulate the cured paste deposit with a dielectric coating. The heater element will be DC.

The maker of the graphite paste gives the sheet resistance as <20 Ω/‪square/25μm.
I want to calculate the resistance of the paste deposit, but most of the paste deposit for the heater element will be in curved sections rather than straight lines. I can calculate the resistance for a straight line of graphite paste by calculating how many squares will fit into the line, but I would like to know how much the resistance will vary when the deposit is curved.

In this discussion
[Does a coiled wire have a higher resistance than straight wire?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/176160/does-a-coiled-wire-have-a-higher-resistance-than-straight-wire)
many people say the resistance will not vary significantly between a straight wire and a curved/coiled wire, so my first question is - would this hold true for a deposit of cured graphite paste as well as a wire?

I have been trying to think of the sheet resistance for one curved section - basically a half-donut shape with an inner diameter of 0.6mm and a deposit width of 0.2mm.
[image]

This page
https://www.thinfilm.com/resistors.html
says that

> “The resistor “square” in the corner area(s) of a bent style resistor
> (e.g. an “L” shape or serpentine design) should be counted as 0.56 the
> value of the sheet resistance.”

Would this mean that the sheet resistance for a half-donut shape would be *less* than a straight line of the same length?

As I say, I can calculate the resistance for a straight line of graphite paste by calculating how many squares will fit into the line - can I still use this method of estimating resistance if the line is curved? Perhaps fitting squares into a straight line the same length and width as the curved line and then adjusting the value?

If anyone has any suggestions on estimating the resistance for these curved sections, I would appreciate any advice!

Comment: Hand make one and measure it.

Comment: Also consider that the electrons will not want to flow through the outer edges of the curve when the inner edge is a shorter distance; may result in uneven heating. Definitely ditto Andy.

Comment: @Andy aka Thanks for your comment. It is difficult for me to make one so small with the resources that I have -  could I just make a bigger one? If the bigger one had the same proportions, and the same thickness, would the resistance be the same? Can I use the bigger model to draw conclusions about the smaller one?

Comment: Make a bigger one and one half size.

Comment: Note that the width of the electrode into which the current enters and exits will affect the result since current spreads and takes some distance to do so out when entering a plane and re-narrows similarly to exit the plane. So making multiple continuous sections will be more representative due to proportionally less "end point". Might be easier to cut carbon paper or something to make it large.

Comment: This https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/316369/50872 might help

Answer (score 1):

The calculation can be done numerically. It's a relatively simple 2-dimensional problem. It's likely not worth it unless you are already up to speed on the software, in which case you'd not be asking the question.

Make a scale model and measure it. If you print the model, print a simple resistor at the same time to establish the sheet resistivity. You could also use any material of known resistivity and thickness or known sheet resistance, but the classic approach is to use Teledeltos paper (around 2k-6k\$\Omega/\square\$), silver paint and an Xacto knife. It's fairly hard to source these days (mostly seems to come from the UK). Bob Pease (RIP) wrote an article on using it.

There's probably no point in getting too picky about the results since you are unlikely to be able to control the thickness and resistivity all that well. Printing that fine a line will likely result in artifacts at the edges from the screen mesh, if screen printing is used. Those artifacts will **not** scale. It will be sensitive to squeegee pressure, speed and angle (and a bunch of other things!) if printed with a screen or stencil. Other than that, the resistance should be the same for the same sheet resistance whether you make it size-as or 10:1.

Probably +/-20% would be a good result in a non-production situation with limited control of the variables. I would not be surprised if it was much worse.

My rough seat-of-the-pants ballpark guesstimate is that if you take the length between 1/4 and 1/3 of the way from the inside to the outside you'll get an answer that's maybe close enough. So around \$R_S\cdot\pi\cdot (0.3 + 0.2a)/0.2\$ where 0.25 < a < 0.33 or around 112\$\Omega\$ for the section shown for 25um (0.001") thick and 20\$\Omega/\square\$ if I did the sums correctly.

You should pay attention to the watt density as well as the resistance.

Answer (score 0):

As Andy aka has stated, you'll really need to do some experimental work.

As rdtsc has also stated, you'll get less current flow around the outer portion, since the path length (and resistance) will be greater.

I'd start by assuming (and this is a rough approximation) that treating it as a .1 mm by 1.9 mm (pi times the diameter of inner edge) rectangle. I'd guess that this will produce a number within a factor of about 50% of your final result.

There's an old story about Thomas Edison. He hired a new engineer, and asked him to find the volume of an open-ended glass bulb with a complicated shape. At the end of the day, the engineer had made multiple measurements and decomposed the bulb's shape into a bunch of smaller, simpler shapes, then calculated the volume of each and summed the result.

Edison took the bulb, walked to a nearby faucet, and filled the bulb. Then walked back to the engineer and told him to pour the water into a beaker.

Sometimes, it's better to just do it.

Answer (score 0):

Resistance will vary by Length x thickness / width * rho and shape does not matter. Where rho is the surface resistivity in the same units of thickness .